# Ruby How to know what to rescue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, soap

I'm using `eurovat` gem to check a VAT number.

```
Eurovat.check_vat_number vat_number
```

If I run that from irb, sometimes I receive this:

```
SOAP::FaultError: MS_UNAVAILABLE
        from
```

(Nothing appear after "from")

I want to write a `begin rescue` block to rescue those error, but how I do know what to rescue?

I have tried with rescue `SOAP::FaultError` but didn't works

Answer (score 0):

I found the way after a bit of testing:

```
rescue SOAP::FaultError => e
    if e.message == "MS_UNAVAILABLE"
      # @ToDO handle service unavailable exception
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar issue. This might be of use to you:

> MS_UNAVAILABLE means that: "The Member State service is unavailable, try again later or with another Member State".